# Can't tell if HTC One V is GSM or CDMA

Tags: gsm, htc-one-v, cdma

I recently won an HTC One V and I want to sell it, but I'm not sure what carriers it supports. I won it from an HTC stand I went to, and all they said was that the phone was unlocked so that it could be used with any carrier. How can I tell if it's CDMA or GSM? I can't remove the cover to see an ESN or HEX number, and I don't see any spot for a SIM slot. On the label of the phone it has an IMEI number, an S/N number and a P/N number. Any ideas?

I see listings on ebay that say GSM and other listing that say GSM/HSPA. How do I tell?

Comment: Community bump prevention: this question was closed because the question seems to have been abandoned (OP hasn't visited the network for more than 5 years, and no existing answers have score above 0). If anyone can evaluate the existing answers, feel free to vote accordingly and reopen the question (or mod-flag the question requesting for reopening). For anyone else having the same issue, please post a new question and refer to this question as additional context.

Answer (score 0):

Based from [an article on Wikipedia regarding to Electronic Serial Number (ESN)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_serial_number),

> ESNs are currently mainly used with CDMA phones (and were previously used by AMPS and TDMA phones), compared to **International Mobile Equipment Identity (IMEI) numbers used by all GSM phones**.

<sub>(Emphasis mine)</sub>

So, if there is IMEI, then it's GSM. Otherwise, it's CDMA.

Alternatively, [theTuxRacer suggested on the comment](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/32906/cant-tell-if-htc-one-v-is-gsm-or-cdma#comment42635_32906)

> Remove the back cover on the chin. Under the "Made in China" sticker, there should be a small box which should mention something like HTC One V T320e... They are called as Primou U and Primou C for the GSM and CDMA version respectively!

Answer (score -2):

GSM arena provides full description and features of most phones, you can search it.
**OR**
Just search for the device specification on google.